# Download manager for the iPad

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, applications

What's a good (paid or free) download manager app for the iPad? I tried using [iDownloads+ Free](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idownloads-plus-free-download/id429648406?mt=8), but it seems to unreliable when the connection is spotty.

Comment: What are you looking for to make an app "good"?

Comment: @DanielL: Something that doesn't break the downloads when the connection is spotty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Atomic Webbrowser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atomic-web-browser-full-screen/id347929410?mt=8)

This is a very advanced web browser with a **Download Manager**.

- Download a file or image in the background.
- Simultaneous downloads.
- Suspend and resume downloads.

[image]